# How to get members of a microsoft outlook distribution group programmatically

Tags: python, python-3.x, outlook

I work at a lawfirm

I have a python script that uses the sendgrid api to send an email to a group of people once a day.
this group has a corresponding ms outlook 'distribution list'. This list gets changed frequently. People get added or removed. To avoid having to check for changes in the distribution list and then manually change my hardcoded list of email addresses in the py script is there anyway to get the distribution list into my code.

Our server is not an exchange server.

I would like to avoid using a hacky method such as selenium or other scraping if possible.

I found this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-get-members-of-an-exchange-distribution-list

but as i mentioned i do not believe it is an exchange server.

I also have encountered solutions using the win32 library but this script runs on a linux vm.

Is there a way to do this via the graph api ?

Microsoft is an enormous confusing black hole for me so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Why get the members? Just send the email to the group.

Comment: @ThomasWeller is there a way to send to a distribution group via sendgrid (or any other mail lib) ? that would be optimal but i was not aware that was an option

Comment: Sorry, I don't know sendgrid, but in our company, every distribution list also has an email address with the same name. If I send an email to hamburg@example.com, then the email will reach all recipients in Hamburg, because that distribution list contains all people in Hamburg.

Comment: @ThomasWeller damn, this is embarrassing i did not even consider that it was anything but a contact object that could only be referenced in outlook